# Weird behaviour with plugin being called more than once

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-select2

I am trying to call a plugin more than once and it never works after the first time.

Strange

Within my code I have a `ul` within a `div`.

```
<div id="#optionalSearchOptions"> <ul> </ul> </div>
```

So I have some other code that appends to that:

```
$("#optionalSearchOptions ul").append("<li> 
<div class='button' style='position:relative'>
<select id='"+ id+"' style='width:200px'> <option></option></select></div></li>");
```

This works OK.

So to know when I am appending to the `ul` a trigger is set every time the append is run.

$(window).trigger('convertBoxes', [id, title] );

Within the `document.ready` I listen for the trigger.

```
$(window).on('convertBoxes', function (event, param1, param2){

  var tmpName = "#" + param1 ;
  newSelect2(tmpName, param2);
});
```

So for each new `li` created the `newSelect2` function is run.

This is the function `newSelect2`:

```
function newSelect2(id, name) {

    console.log(id);

    $(id).select2({
        placeholder: name
    });

}
```

This should for each new `li` run the `select2` plugin - but it only runs it on the first time, I am not sure why.

Can anyone help?

here is a js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dwhitmarsh/MfJ4B/5

try adding a movie then adding another

Comment: "_So to know when I am appending to the ul a trigger is set every time the append is run._" Where is this done? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: i didnt add that because would be alot of code but i know from the console log that its being run

Comment: the problem is with the select2 being run more than once - dont understand why it isnt

Comment: Maybe you could try manually calling the function with each append instead of using the events. They might be the cause of the glitch.

Comment: But why would the console log work.. Must be something to do with the plugin..

Comment: how do you change/set the id value. cannot say anything from your code if it is updating the id. (<select id='"+ id+"'...)

Comment: jsfiddle.net/dwhitmarsh/MfJ4B/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is this code:

```
$("#optionalSearchOptions ul")
```

after the first select2 is created as part of its markup it adds a ul. so now your selector is matching the ul inside the markup select2 added and the second select2 gets created inside the first.

instead you should say

```
$("#optionalSearchOptions>ul")
```

meaning match a ul that is a direct child of the options div. alternatively throw a class on the ul to make it a bit less fragile.

see it work here with the direct child selector and your fiddle cleaned up:
http://jsfiddle.net/MfJ4B/9/